# Question about prove of Absolute Convergence Test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I'm self-studying from the book [Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950605) and I have a question about the proof of the Absolute Convergence Test (theorem 2.7.6 on page 65).

The author states that since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges, we know that, given $\epsilon >0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
\begin{equation}
|a_{m+1}| + |a_{m+2}| + \cdots + |a_n| < \epsilon
\end{equation}
for all $n > m \geq N$.

My question is: why this is true? I don't think the author has proved this anywhere in the book.

Intuitively, I can sort of understand the above statement only if the "tail" of the series becomes increasingly small (which naively seems to a property of the convergent series, but I'm not sure if this is always true). But this all seems very "handwavy". Can anybody shed some light on my confusion?

Comment: The sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|$ converges and is, thus, ....

Comment: @DavidMitra a Cauchy sequence? I'm not sure how this is going to help me though.

Comment: Yes. What is $S_{n}-S_m$?

Comment: @DavidMitra $|s_n - s_m| = |a_{m+1} + a_{m+2} + \cdots + a_n | < \epsilon$. But this still doesn't tell me that $|a_{m+1}| + |a_{m+2}| + \cdots + |a_n | < \epsilon $, right?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong series. Look at the partial sums for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$. You're assuming this converges. $S_n-S_m= |a_{m+1}|+\cdots+|a_n|$.

Comment: @DavidMitra ahhhh, of course, silly me! Thanks for your answer! If you post it as an answer, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges. This, by definition means that the sequence of partial sums, $(S_m)$, given by $S_m=\sum\limits_{n=1}^m |a_n|$, converges.

If you look closely, you should be able to see that your condition is just saying $(S_m)$ is a Cauchy sequence (which it is, of course).